# Openerp 7 rml reports conditional in story/pto markup

Tags: python, odoo, rml

I've done my google search without success (obvious) and i'm here to ask if someone know how to add a conditional on a `<story>` or `<pto>` markup like we can do in `<para>`.

Here is my problem, i've 2 types of documents, invoice and second print of an invoice. The second one is a little differente, only could have Original and delete other 3 pages that a normal invoice report have (duplicated, triple and quad).

Here is the strutucture of my code:

```
<story>
  <pto>
     <ANOTHER MARKUPS LIKE PARA/>
     <para style="terp_default_Bold_8">ORIGINAL</para>
     <ANOTHER MARKUPS LIKE PARA/>
  </pto>
</story>
<story>
  <pto>
     <ANOTHER MARKUPS LIKE PARA/>
     <para style="terp_default_Bold_8">Duplicated</para>
     <ANOTHER MARKUPS LIKE PARA/>
  </pto>
</story>
<!-- same for triple and quad -->
```

What can i do to hide second the second `<story>` with a condition to differentiate the documents?

Comment: Not an answer to your question....but why are you using `rml` instead of `Qweb`

Comment: my file is .rml...

Comment: sorry, i miss understood your question. I didn't know that Qweb could be used on openerp too.. im newbie with this framework

Comment: If you have the possibility to use QWeb, please use QWeb :-)

Comment: Oh it's OpenERP 7? No QWeb then :/

Comment: thanks anyway... looks like no1 have answers :(

Comment: Use different templates to let the user chooses which document to print from `print` menu.